# margin is not working.can any one check my code and help me?

Tags: html, css

I want align all the divs inside a div center.So i am giving margin to the outer div but margin is not working.i don't know what is the problem.I am giving width also...
is giving float is the problem.I read that margin has problems with float and width. Is that the problem??

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#products_main {
  clear: both;
  margin: 50px:;
}

.product_item {
  clear: both;
}

.product_item_image {
  float: left;
}

.product_item_content {
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
  font-size: 200%;
  align: justify;
}

.product_item_heading {
  width: 75%;
  color: #06F;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="products_main">
    <div id="products">
      <div class="product_item">
        <div>
          <h2 class="product_item_heading">
            Industrial Automation
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="product_item_image">
          <img src="images/products/Industrial automation/images/Oscillator.jpg" width="350" height="200">
        </div>
        <div class="product_item_content">
          Oscillators:Quartz crystal Oscillators,crystal resonators,Oscillator modules
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: syntax error : you have `:`

Answer (score 0):

Your css is wrong. remove `:` from `50px`

```css
*
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#products_main
{
    clear:both;
    margin:50px ;
}
.product_item
{
    clear: both;
}
.product_item_image
{
    float: left;
}
.product_item_content
{
    float: left;
    width:65%;
    font-size:200%;
    text-align:justify;
}
.product_item_heading
{
    width:75%;
    color:#06F;
}
```

```html
<div id="products_main">
    <div id="products">
        <div class="product_item">
            <div>
                <h2 class="product_item_heading">
                    Industrial Automation
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="product_item_image">
                <img src="images/products/Industrial automation/images/Oscillator.jpg" width="350" height="200">
            </div>
            <div class="product_item_content">
                Oscillators:Quartz crystal Oscillators,crystal resonators,Oscillator modules for defence &  Space applications will be supplied with  custom-made.Oscillators like  TCXO,VCXO,OCXO  etc.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only takes a comment

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the colon `:` after 50px in `margin:50px: ;` and it will work!